# Bcryptjs Async not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, bcrypt

I am using bcryptjs to hash and compare passwords on my node server. Here is my function:

```
this.testPassword = function(pass1, pass2, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(pass1, pass2, function(err, res) {
        callback(err, res);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

And the function call:

```
context.runQuery("...", function(resp, err) {
    if (!err) {
        testPassword("test11", "test12", function(err2, resp2) {

        });
    }           
});
```

Despite the fact that this should be async, it slows down the server for 200ms. Is this an issue with the bcrypt-js module or with my implementation.

Comment: Code seems fine to me. Not really sure why you mean by "slows down"... but just because something is async in JS/node doesn't mean it will not impact performance... If that operation is very intensive, it will slow down (because it's not physically concurrent). You could use something like workers to obtain better results I guess.

Comment: So what is the point of using async?

Comment: To not block execution, but that doesn't mean performance is better because it's not taking advantage of physical concurrent capabilities. So... it should slow down, but it shouldn't block.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the number of SaltRounds used for encryption. Reducing it even by 1 can show drastic performance improvement.

Here is the extract from bcrypt [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#a-note-on-rounds) to compare the performance based on number of SaltRounds:

> - rounds=8 : ~40 hashes/sec
> - rounds=9 : ~20 hashes/sec
> - rounds=10: ~10 hashes/sec
> - rounds=11: ~5  hashes/sec
> - rounds=12: 2-3 hashes/sec
> - rounds=13: ~1 sec/hash
> - rounds=14: ~1.5 sec/hash
> - rounds=15: ~3 sec/hash
> - rounds=25: ~1 hour/hash
> - rounds=31: 2-3 days/hash

Hope this helps

Comment: It will matter because the `callback` will not be invoked unless the compare function has completed. See the documentation link provided. Also, I recommend that you test it to see the difference.

Comment: Ive already reduced it to 8. It still lags. I figured async would fix that